# What "tabloid", "bikini", "heroin", "escalator", "trampoline", and "aspirin" have in common

Tags: meaning

This is a puzzle for Christmas. What do the following words have in common?

*tabloid, bikini, heroin, escalator, trampoline, aspirin*

Comment: They can all provide a lift?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a puzzle.

Comment: @ColinFine It's about etymology.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Had I not already awarded the 'correct answer', that would certainly have deserved such!

Comment: @ColinFine Happy Christmas, Colin!

Comment: If I ***google*** that list of words and ignore all the links to this very question on ELU (and the "Hot Questions" pane in several other SO sites), I'm led straight to [*...formerly registered marks that, due to failure of their owners to police and enforce their rights, were invalidated, declared generic and allowed to be used by anyone*](http://benmetcalfe.com/blog/2006/10/google-can-go-shove-their-lexicographical-advice-up-their-ass/comment-page-1/). I've no idea if Google fancy their chances at stopping me from using "their" word uncapitalised and without attribution (but they *won't!* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The law here is a good deal more complex than it might appear at first. Otherwise people wouldn't talk about *Tesco's weetabix', Sainsbury's marmite, and Waitrose's Horlicks* (or things like that). Why wouldn't Tesco simply call their shredded wheat, *Shredded Wheat*? Answer: they can't because Unilever, or Nestle or someone owns the rights.

Comment: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @WS": There's a world of difference between *Tesco* calling their malted drink *"Horlicks"* (trademark owners GlaxoSmithKline would win a lawsuit in seconds), and ***me*** using "their" word in some other context (GlaxoSmithKline would be laughed out of court if they were stupid enough to gun for me). The law is there to prevent *passing off, fraud*, not to restrict my freedom to use language as I see fit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe these words:

> were originally ***brand names***.

### [Tabloid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabloid_(newspaper_format)#History)

> The word "tabloid" comes from the name given by the London based pharmaceutical company Burroughs Wellcome & Co. to the compressed tablets they marketed as "Tabloid" pills in the late 1880s.

### [Bikini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bikini#Etymology)

> French mechanical engineer Louis Réard introduced a design he named the "bikini," taking the name from the Bikini Atoll in the Pacific Ocean

### [Heroin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroin#Etymology)

> In 1895, the German drug company Bayer marketed diacetylmorphine as an over-the-counter drug under the trademark name Heroin

### [Escalator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalator#Etymology)

> Charles Seeberger created the word "escalator" in 1900, to coincide with his device’s debut at the Exposition Universelle. According to his own account, in 1895, his legal counsel advised him to name his new invention, and he then set out to devise a title for it on his own

### [Trampoline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline)

> George Nissen had heard the word on a demonstration tour in Mexico in the late 1930s and decided to use an anglicized form as the trademark for the apparatus.[3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroin#Etymology)

### [Aspirin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirin#History)

> The new drug, formally acetylsalicylic acid, was named Aspirin by Bayer AG after the botanical name for meadowsweet, Spiraea ulmaria, derived from "acetyl" and Spirsäure, an old German name for salicylic acid derived from the Latin Spiraea ulmaria.[

Comment: Congratulations on being first with the right answer. Well done! And congratulations on Sunderland's victory at St James Park yesterday. I watched it on MotD. Were you there?

Comment: Colud the name of an island be considered a 'brand name'?

Comment: @Josh61 As I understand it the name of the clothing item (if you can call it that) was patented by the Frenchman Louis Reard in 1947. That is what connects all the words I gave. They have all at some point been protected. I've no idea how difficult it was for Reard to convince the French 'Bureau de Marques' (or whatever they are called) about the originality of the name. So far as I am aware no one has yet patented 'the birthday suit', though you see a lot of them in France!

Comment: 'Bikini' is an eponym. But then Boney was a warrior.

Comment: @WS2 - I wasn't there unfortunately but my friends and I all watched it in our local.  Very happy!

Comment: And plus one for the ! -- a real X-Mas surprise. Thanks.

Comment: @WS2 Patent != Trademark

Comment: Aspirin is still a Bayer trademark here in Canada. Everyone else must label theirs as ASA.

Comment: @TomRobinson I've heard that before. Do you know anything about the reason why Canada is an exception? Because Bayer lost this and other trademarks as part of the terms of the Treaty of Versailles in 1919.